# iOS Urban Airship : Push notification with tags not receiving

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

In my iOS application i am adding tags in following way

```
UAPush* push = [UAPush shared];
[push setTags:tags];//update locally
[push updateRegistration];//update server
NSLog(@"Updated tags %@", push.tags);
```

But when I sending push message with one of these tags push notification is not coming to the device.

Comment: Check your error console to see if anything sent:http://docs.urbanairship.com/dashboard/getting_started.html#error-console

Comment: Thanks dperconti.But i am unable to see the error console.Is permission required to access the error console?

Comment: You shouldn't.. What I would suggest is to make sure that your dev & prod environments are not crossed. EG: if your Urban Airship app is a development, your apple credentials will need to be development. See:
https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/69603958-Rejected-Device-Tokens

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
UAPush* push = [UAPush shared];
[push addTags:tags];
[push updateRegistration];
```

or

```
UAPush* push = [UAPush shared];
[push addTagsToCurrentDevice:tags];
[push updateRegistration];
```